# Malformed Lambda proxy response from AWS API Gateway calling a Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

In my project i create a py function for check and modify my google calendar like this:

```
def main(event, context):

    ck_app = check(event['calID'], event['datada'], event['dataa'])

    if not ck_app: insert(event['calID'], event['datada'], event['dataa'], event['email'])

    return {
        "isBase64Encoded": False,
        "statusCode": '200',
        "headers": {},
        "body": {'input': event,
                 'busy': ck_app,
                 'guest_email': event['email']}   
    }
```

when i test it on my lambda all done, but whe i create an API from lambda:

[image]

and test it the result is:

> Wed Dec 20 13:35:58 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
>   Wed Dec 20 13:35:58 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 502

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 43):

API Gateway expects a json body so you should use something like this

```
import json
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps({'input': event,
                        'busy': ck_app,
                        'guest_email': event['email']})
}
```

Hope this helps you forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot! read error carefully i see that error seems related to check method calL :ck_app = check(event['calID'], event['datada'], event['dataa']) that return a single parameter. Is it possible??

Comment: hi there, can't really help you with that i am afraid. i am just custom with lambda but have no idea how the check function works. Would suggest to make a new question to find it out.

Comment: @AleMal You just need to pass string using json.dumps in "body"